# How to change fieldset with form to textarea triggable by a button?

Tags: html

I have this code that needs to be adapted to work with something similar to the code below the commented line. If I can make it without many changes would be perfect so that I don't need to change the CSS and so. Any help? Many thanks in advance.

```
<!-- The code to be adapted is this: -->

<form action="" id="search-form">
 <fieldset>
  <input type="text" class="text" /><input type="submit" value="Search" class="submit" />
 </fieldset>
</form>

<!-- The new code that I got from the web and that needs to be adapted to the old one
is the following: -->

<textarea id="Blah"></textarea><button onclick="search()">Search</button>
<script>
function search() {
var Blah = document.getElementById("Blah").value;
location.replace("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + Blah + "");
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can do this with JS but it will make it complex for you to understand, so just change a little bit CSS, It's very easy and short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm imagining you probably want something like

```js
document.querySelector("#searchButton").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    const value = document.querySelector("#searchBox").value;
    const url = `https://www.google.com/search?q=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`;
    window.location.replace(url);
});
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <input type="text" class="search" id="searchBox">
    <Button id="searchButton">Search</button>
</fieldset>
```

The `id` attribute on HTML elements allows you to access them via JavaScript. There's a wealth of tutorials online if you want to learn JavaScript deeply, but the basics of what this is doing is:

- It finds the HTML element with the `id` of `searchButton`, and adds a `click` listener to it --- this gets triggered whenever that element is clicked.
- In that listener, we find the value of the text input with the `id` of `searchBox`.
- We compose our new URL. One thing I've added here is a call to `encodeURIComponent` to correctly handle the cases where they try searching for something which contains a character which isn't valid in a URL --- for example, the space character etc.

Comment: Yes, that helped a lot! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was not working as I wanted, but a little trick made it work.
Here is my final code:

```
<form action="" id="search-form">
<fieldset>
    <input type="text" class="search" id="searchBox">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="submit" />
</fieldset>
</form>

<script>  
let myvar;
document.querySelector(".submit").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    const value = document.querySelector("#searchBox").value;
    myvar = `https://www.google.com/search?q=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`;
 setTimeout(callurl, 1);
 return false;
});
function callurl() {
  location.assign(myvar);
  return false;
}
</script>
```